# phpImageWorkshop: Removing a layer after saving

Tags: php

In the phpImageWorkshop documentation (http://phpimageworkshop.com/doc/13/saving.html) it says:

> *...after saving, you'll be able to continue to use your document and
>   to perform some actions on its sublayers, really convenient !*

However, after calling `save()` I'm unable to remove the watermark layer.

I start by loading the photo and watermark and resize the photo:

```
$photo = PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop::initFromPath($tmp_name);
$mark = PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop::initFromPath($watermark);
$photo->resizeInPixel(960, null, true);
```

And then I add the watermark, save the photo, then remove the watermark (so I can make other sizes without a watermark without creating a new object):

```
$photo->addLayer(1, $mark, 0, 0, 'LB');
$photo->save($path, $filename, false, null, 80); // file correctly has watermark
$photo->remove(1);

$photo->resizeInPixel(550, null, true);
$photo->save($path, $filename, false, null, 80); // file has watermark, not correct
```

This does not delete the watermark layer. However, if I call `remove()` before `save()` it will remove the watermark:

```
$photo->addLayer(1, $mark, 0, 0, 'LB');
$photo->remove(1); // calling remove() before save removes watermark
$photo->save($path, $filename, false, null, 80);  // file does not have watermark
```

I cannot understand why this is happening, since the documentation clearly says calling `save()` does not change the layers.

I've confirmed that the watermark layer is being put on layer level 1, and it works OK if I do not call `save()`.

Comment: Is it resizeInPixel merging the layers? You are better off addressing the support forum directly for this: https://github.com/Sybio/ImageWorkshop/issues

Comment: Unfortunately that support forum is a bit dead. Seems like if you do happen to get a reply, it won't be for at least a month. I was hoping to get a faster response on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the documentation saying `you'll be able to continue to use your document`, the fact is that the `save()` function calls `getResult()` which returns a merged resource image (this is in ImageWorkshopLayer.php)

However, if you create a 'base layer' and add the photo and watermark on top of it, the save() function appears to merge to the base layer - leaving the photo and mark untouched, so you can remove the mark and re-save (which causes the photo to be re-merged onto the base layer) i.e.

```
$baseimg = PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop::initVirginLayer(1024,800);

$photo = PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop::initFromPath("test.png");
$mark = PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop::initFromPath("test2.png");

$iphoto= $baseimg->addLayerOnTop($photo, 0, 0, 'LB');
$imark=  $baseimg->addLayerOnTop($mark, 0, 0, 'LB');

$baseimg->resizeInPixel(960, null, true);

// file correctly has watermark
$baseimg->save(__DIR__, "test_out.png", false, null, 80); 

$baseimg->remove($imark['id']);

// file correctly has no watermark
$baseimg->save(__DIR__, "test_out2.png", false, null, 80);
```

Note that I use the return value from `addLayerOnTop()` to determine the 'id' pf the layer to remove.

**EDIT:** although the above works, it is not ideal because you really need the resulting image to be the size of the re-sized photo. Also I found that once the photo is made a layer, you have to resize that layer (not the original photo) so...

```
// load photo and mark
$photo = PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop::initFromPath("test.png");
$mark = PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop::initFromPath("test2.png");

// resize the photo 1st time
$photo->resizeInPixel(960,null, true);
$width= $photo->getWidth();
$height= $photo->getHeight();

// make empty base image same size as photo
$baseimg = PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop::initVirginLayer($width,$height);

// add photo and mark onto base image
$iphoto= $baseimg->addLayerOnTop($photo, 0, 0, 'LT');
$imark=  $baseimg->addLayerOnTop($mark, 0, 0, 'LT');

$photoid= $iphoto['id'];    // get layer id's
$markid=  $imark['id'];

// file correctly has watermark
$baseimg->save(__DIR__, "test_out.png", false, null, 80); 

// remove mark layer
$baseimg->remove($imark['id']);

// resize photo again
// - photo is now a layer in baseimg
$baseimg->layers[$photoid]->resizeInPixel(550,null, true);
$width= $baseimg->layers[$photoid]->getWidth();
$height= $baseimg->layers[$photoid]->getHeight();

// crop baseimg to match photo size
$baseimg->cropInPixel($width,$height);

// file correctly has no watermark
$baseimg->save(__DIR__, "test_out2.png", false, null, 80);
```

That seems to work fine now.

Comment: Nice! Thanks Tony! It's 5:40am here in Thailand and my eyes are barely open, but I'll give it a try in the "morning". Thanks again.

Comment: Your method worked perfectly, Tony. Nice and fast too. Thanks again.